# Show these sequences converge and determine the limit of each.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Using the definition of convergence in metric spaces, show that the following sequences converge and find its limit.

1.) $a_n(x)=\frac{n}{n+1}x^2+\frac{2}{n}x+3$ in $(C[0,1],||.||_1)$

To begin we assume $a_n(x)$ converges to $3$ as $n\longrightarrow \infty$.

Then
$$||a_n(x)-3||=\int_0^1 \frac{n}{n+1}x^3 dx +\int_0^1\frac{2}{n}x dx+\int_0^1 3 dx.$$

This gives $\frac{n}{3n+3}+\frac{2}{2n}+3 \longrightarrow 3$ as $n\longrightarrow 3$. Thus, our limit of convergence is $3$.

2.) $b_n(x)=(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{n+1}{n}, \frac{n^2+1}{n^2+2})$ in $(\mathbb{R}^3, \mid\mid . \mid \mid_2)$.

To begin we assume $b_n(x)$ converges to $1$.

Then
$$||b_n(x)-1||_2^2.$$
I'm not sure how to calculate this for a $b_n(x)$?

3.) $c_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}+(2+\frac{1}{2^n})x$ in $(C[0,1],||.||_\infty)$.

To begin we assume $c_n(x)$ converges to $2x$.

Then
$$||c_n(x)-2x||_\infty =\sup_{0\leq x\leq 1} |c_n(x)-2x|=1.$$
I'm not entirely sure if this is correct or if we should use the `epsilon' definition?

Comment: $\frac{n}{n+1}$ goes to $1$, not $0$ as $n \to \infty$, so why would $a_n(x)$ go to $3$?

Comment: Also, what does "$b_n(x)$ converges to $1$" even mean? $b_n(x)$ is a three-dimensional vector, so whatever it converges to, it must be a vector also...

Comment: Even after the correction suggested by @fgp, your "proof" of convergence for (1) is incomplete--you didn't actually show that the quantity you computed tends to zero, did you? You should compute the integrals explicitly, or at least estimate them from above, and show the value (or bound) tends to zero as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, I thought $b_n(x)\longrightarrow (0,1,1)$. Is this not correct?

Comment: Would $c_n\longrightarrow 2x$? And am I correct in saying we calculate the supremum?

Answer (score 1):

For $(a_n)$ the pointwise limit is $a(x)=x^2+3$ and we have
$$||a_n-a||_1=\int_0^1 \left|\frac{-x^2}{n+1}+\frac{2}nx\right|dx\le\frac{1}{3(n+1)}+\frac{1}{n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$
hence
$$a_n\xrightarrow{||.||_1}a$$

by the same method prove that
$$b_n\xrightarrow{||.||_2}(0,1,1)$$

Comment: Ok, so $a_n \longrightarrow a$, does $a=x^2+3$? So the limit of $a_n$ is $x^2+3$? Also, I'm not sure how you obtained the RHS of he inequality above?

Comment: Yes I proved that $a$ is the $||.||_1$ limit of $(a_n)$. For the RHS of the inequality I just used the triangle inequality.